# Catalan language "ela geminada"

Tags: languages, babel, characters

The language setting for my document is Catalan `babel`. The Catalan alphabet includes a letter called *ela geminada*, spelled with two lower-case `l` separated by the interpunct `·` (i.e. "cel·la" or "pel·lícula". More information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct#Catalan).

I would like to input `l·l` from the keyboard rather than writing `\lgem`, which is the command given by the `babel` package in the `catalan` mode. However, when I type `l·l`, the spacing is too big, and I would like it to look as the output of the original command.

An image to clarify this:

[image]

Comment: Almost a year ago, in the CervanTeX mailing list Javier Bezos (who's now the supporter of the babel package) posted about the ela geminada. The answer of Ignasi was part of that thread. I hope you can read it in the feed of the list or somewhere else. I think can be useful for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some time ago, one of my university colleagues gave me the following code to use the *punt volat* (`Shift+3` on a spanish keyboard) as an active character. Sometimes I use it but I don't have it on any 'official' style file, then it's easier for me to use `"l` or `\lgem{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%Definició de la ela geminada per tal que accepti el punt volat del teclat
\def·#1{%
  \ifmmode
    \cdot #1
    %\csname normal@char\string"\endcsname l%
  \else%
    \def\argument{#1}%
    \if\argument l%
      \leftllkern=0pt\rightllkern=0pt\raiselldim=0pt%
      \setbox0\hbox{l}\setbox1\hbox{l\/}\setbox2\hbox{.}%
      \advance\raiselldim by \the\fontdimen5\the\font
      \advance\raiselldim by -\ht2%
      \leftllkern=-.25\wd0%
      \advance\leftllkern by \wd1%
      \advance\leftllkern by -\wd0%
      \rightllkern=-.25\wd0%
      \advance\rightllkern by -\wd1%
      \advance\rightllkern by \wd0%
      \allowhyphens\discretionary{-}{l}%
      {\hbox{}\kern\leftllkern\raise\raiselldim\hbox{.}%
        \kern\rightllkern\hbox{l}}\allowhyphens%
    \else
      \if\argument L%
        \leftllkern=0pt\rightllkern=0pt\raiselldim=0pt%
        \setbox0\hbox{L}\setbox1\hbox{L\/}\setbox2\hbox{.}%
        \advance\raiselldim by .5\ht0%
        \advance\raiselldim by -.5\ht2%
        \leftllkern=-.125\wd0%
        \advance\leftllkern by \wd1%
        \advance\leftllkern by -\wd0%
        \rightllkern=-\wd0%
        \divide\rightllkern by 6%
        \advance\rightllkern by -\wd1%
        \advance\rightllkern by \wd0%
        \allowhyphens\discretionary{-}{L}%
        {\hbox{}\kern\leftllkern\raise\raiselldim\hbox{.}%
           \kern\rightllkern\hbox{L}}\allowhyphens%
      \else
        #1
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  }

\begin{document}
cel·la
CEL·LA
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi, I will use it in all my personal and local catalan documents, and the babel commands as egreg commented in the other ones. _Gràcies_.

Comment: @Ignasi for some reason this code fails when · is in `\section{}`, `\subsection{}` and so on (e.g, `\section{Oscil·ladors}`). Any clue?

Comment: @AlfredoHernández: You can use `\section{\protect Oscil·ladors}` but it will fail composing table of contents. I think Javier's solution is better. [Here](http://listserv.rediris.es/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1303&L=ES-TEX&D=0&1=ES-TEX&9=A&J=on&d=Ninguna+coincidencia%3BCoincidir%3BCoincidencias&z=4&P=8765) you can read the thread in CervanTeX mentioned by Aradnix

Comment: I had tried it before and I didn't understand `\newbox\LL\hbox{l·l L·l l·L L·L}`. Nonetheless I deleted that line and the code works flawlessly, thanks both ;)

Answer (score 14):

You have several options available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{Ŀ}{\L.}
\newunicodechar{ŀ}{\l.}

\begin{document}
CE\Lgem A -- ce\lgem a

CE\L.LA -- ce\l.la

CE"LA -- ce"la

CEĿLA -- ceŀla

\end{document}
```

The last uses the Unicode characters (and requires UTF-8), the first three work in any input encoding.

[image]

Comment: Be aware that `ĿL` is a bad way of writing `L·L`. See the 2nd point in http://bloc.totssom.cat/2012/11/21/campanya-per-a-la-normalitzacio-tipografica-de-la-ela-geminada-l%C2%B7l/#post-1871

Comment: @Oriol I've found nothing at unicode.org saying that U+013F is deprecated. Can you add official information? What I think of it is that Catalan made the wrong choice: it should have been chosen `ly` (on the `ny` model) or `lh` (like Portuguese) for `ll`, and `ll` for `ĿL`. It's too late now, of course.

Comment: It seems `ĿL` is not deprecated and http://www.l·l.cat is wrong, as explained http://www.b-j.cat/teclats/#4.3. But it is true that unicode says (page 4 of http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf) that the preferred representation of U+0140 (`ŀ`) in Catalan is U+006C (`l`) U+00B7 (`·`). And I agree we made the wrong choice.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution, based on the previous one. Redefining directly · is not a good idea (problems with TOC, for example), and the proper way is redefining the LICR object `\textperiodcentered`. I even consider impossible cases, like l·L. I wrote it long ago and posted to the list es-tex (CervanTeX), and here I just copy and paste it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[catalan]{babel}

\def\xgem{%
   \ifmmode
 \csname normal@char\string"\endcsname l%
   \else
 \leftllkern=0pt\rightllkern=0pt\raiselldim=0pt
 \setbox0\hbox{l}\setbox1\hbox{l\/}\setbox2\hbox{.}%
 \advance\raiselldim by \the\fontdimen5\the\font
 \advance\raiselldim by -\ht2
 \leftllkern=-.25\wd0%
 \advance\leftllkern by \wd1
 \advance\leftllkern by -\wd0
 \rightllkern=-.25\wd0%
 \advance\rightllkern by -\wd1
 \advance\rightllkern by \wd0
 \allowhyphens\discretionary{-}{}%
 {\kern\leftllkern\raise\raiselldim\hbox{.}%
   \kern\rightllkern}\allowhyphens
   \fi
   }
\def\Xgem{%
   \ifmmode
 \csname normal@char\string"\endcsname L%
   \else
 \leftllkern=0pt\rightllkern=0pt\raiselldim=0pt
 \setbox0\hbox{L}\setbox1\hbox{L\/}\setbox2\hbox{.}%
 \advance\raiselldim by .5\ht0
 \advance\raiselldim by -.5\ht2
 \leftllkern=-.125\wd0%
 \advance\leftllkern by \wd1
 \advance\leftllkern by -\wd0
 \rightllkern=-\wd0%
 \divide\rightllkern by 6
 \advance\rightllkern by -\wd1
 \advance\rightllkern by \wd0
 \allowhyphens\discretionary{-}{}%
 {\kern\leftllkern\raise\raiselldim\hbox{.}%
   \kern\rightllkern}\allowhyphens
   \fi
   }

\newbox\LL\hbox{l·l L·l l·L L·L}

% No lo uso, pero es como podría guardarse el valor
% anterior:
\expandafter\let\expandafter\saveperiodcentered
   \csname T1\string\textperiodcentered \endcsname

% Y aquí está el quid. No hago nada con el argumento, pero
% se podría usar para, por ejemplo, considerar los 4 casos
% por separado:
\DeclareTextCommand{\textperiodcentered}{T1}[1]{%
   \ifnum\spacefactor=998
 \Xgem
   \else
 \xgem
   \fi#1}

\begin{document}

Por defecto:

\leavevmode\box\LL

\sfcode`L=998

Corregido:

l·l L·l l·L L·L

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain what does the `\newbox\LL\hbox{l·l L·l l·L L·L}` line make in your preamble? Anyway, thanks for your solution; very handy.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández It just stores some examples to show how · looks by default.

Answer (score 0):

Using the last replys I think that the best version it is this (because improves the problem of babel-catalan consisting of using "." instead "·", the lector can realised about this using CTRL+F in the text, for example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{Ŀ}{L·}
\newunicodechar{ŀ}{l·}

usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\renewcommand{\lgem}{l·l}
\renewcommand{\Lgem}{L·L}

\def\xgem{%
   \ifmmode
 \csname normal@char\string"\endcsname l%
   \else
 \leftllkern=0pt\rightllkern=0pt\raiselldim=0.15em
 \setbox0\hbox{l}\setbox1\hbox{l\/}\setbox2\hbox{$\cdot$}%
 \advance\raiselldim by \the\fontdimen5\the\font
 \advance\raiselldim by -\ht2
 \leftllkern=-.25\wd0%
 \advance\leftllkern by \wd1
 \advance\leftllkern by -\wd0
 \rightllkern=-.25\wd0%
 \advance\rightllkern by -\wd1
 \advance\rightllkern by \wd0
 \allowhyphens\discretionary{-}{}%
 {\kern\leftllkern\raise\raiselldim\hbox{$\cdot$}%
   \kern\rightllkern}\allowhyphens
   \fi
   }
\def\Xgem{%
   \ifmmode
 \csname normal@char\string"\endcsname L%
   \else
 \leftllkern=0pt\rightllkern=0pt\raiselldim=0pt
 \setbox0\hbox{L}\setbox1\hbox{L\/}\setbox2\hbox{$\cdot$}%
 \advance\raiselldim by .5\ht0
 \advance\raiselldim by -.5\ht2
 \leftllkern=-.125\wd0%
 \advance\leftllkern by \wd1
 \advance\leftllkern by -\wd0
 \rightllkern=-\wd0%
 \divide\rightllkern by 6
 \advance\rightllkern by -\wd1
 \advance\rightllkern by \wd0
 \allowhyphens\discretionary{-}{}%
 {\kern\leftllkern\raise\raiselldim\hbox{$\cdot$}%
   \kern\rightllkern}\allowhyphens
   \fi
   }


\DeclareTextCommand{\textperiodcentered}{T1}[1]{%
   \ifnum\spacefactor=998
 \Xgem
   \else
 \xgem
   \fi#1}

\begin{document}
Novel·la

Noveŀla

Nove"la

Nove\lgem a

Nove\l.la 

\end{document}
```

[image: The 4 results are identical]

Comment: You have missed `\sfcode`L=998`.